# How to retrive facility/user from on service record creation in CRM 2011/2013?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4, microsoft-dynamics

I am stugglung with an issue regarding service and facility in CRM. i have created a service in MS CRM 2013 and i have attached a resource (a facility) with it and a selection rule. Now i want some method using which i can identify the facility attached with the service being created. E.g user creates a service in crm and attaches a resource(facility/user) i want to fire plugin on creation of service record which retrieves facility/user from service record and add this to my custom entity.

After doing some research on Google i found this
Go to Service -> Find resourcespecid
Search in resourcespec with this ID 
You'll get GroupObjectId
Search in constraintbasedgroup  entity with GroupObjectId and in this table you will get Constraint field in which you'll get something like follow

resource["Id"] == {250ffa41-ac85-e311-9401-005056bf502e}

retrieve resource Id from Above XML.
This resource id belongs to Resource table in CRM with field Resource Type.

Now i am stuck at this point. I am not able to find any relation between facility and resource entity, hence can not get the facility id attached with the service.

Now my question is How to fetch a facility id from Service? is it possible or not?

Answer (score 0):

The resource ID should be the exactly the same as the primary key ID of the corresponding entity, you need to find the entity type only from the resource table.

Comment: Hi bia thanks,but i have checked this, the resource id what get from resource entity is not the same as the facility unique id. After doing so much googling i have come to conclusion (OR may be assumption) that this is not possible, and i am waiting to some one prove me wrong, but still i didn't get any one :(